# Installing old version of preview

Tags: macos, preview

I recently upgraded to Mac OSX Mountain Lion and everything is running great. However, I liked the outlay of notes in PDF much better in the old Preview (Preview 5.0.3). I was wondering if there was anyway that I could get the old version back and overwrite the new version?

Answer (score 1):

You can try [this guide](http://osxdaily.com/2012/01/27/how-to-install-the-older-preview-app-from-snow-leopard-in-mac-os-x-lion/) at your own risk.

But just go to the View menu and you'll see there are many ways to customize how PDFs can be displayed.

Answer (score 0):

On my Mountain Lion Mac, I still have a Snow Leopard HD where I sometimes boot.  It has Preview 5.0.3.  So I tried running Preview 5.0.3 under Mountain Lion.  I just get the message that it cannot run under this version of OS X.